Cannot connect Flink to Kafka
I am running Docker containers using docker-compose.yml. I am posting log messages which they successfully get published to a Kafka topic but when i am trying to read it to Flink, PyFlink to be accurate, i am getting error:
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factory for identifier 'kafka' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory' in the classpath.

Available factory identifiers are:

blackhole
datagen
filesystem
print
python-input-format

The code i am running is:
def main():
    env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
    t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(environment_settings=env_settings)
    t_env.execute_sql(
        f"""
        CREATE TABLE kafka_test_logs (
            action2 STRING
        ) WITH (
            'connector' = 'kafka',
            'topic' = 'test-logs',
            'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:9092',
            'properties.group.id' = 'flink_group',
            'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
            'format' = 'json',
            'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true'
            )
        """)
      
    t_env.execute_sql("""
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS message_count
        FROM kafka_test_logs
    """).print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

In my docker-compose.yml file i use Flink image: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12
These are the libs in /opt/flink/lib in my JobManager container:
flink-cep-1.18.1.jar
flink-connector-files-1.18.1.jar
flink-connector-kafka-1.17.2.jar
flink-csv-1.18.1.jar
flink-dist-1.18.1.jar
flink-json-1.18.1.jar
flink-scala_2.12-1.18.1.jar
flink-shaded-guava-30.1.1-jre-16.0.jar
flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar
flink-table-planner-loader-1.18.1.jar
flink-table-runtime-1.18.1.jar
kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar
log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar
log4j-api-2.17.1.jar
log4j-core-2.17.1.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar

Not sure if there is a good way to check for compatibility issues with versions of the libs. Any idea what might be the root cause of the error?
I downloaded some libs which i copied to a libs directory in my project and i used volumes to load them to Flink TaskManager and JobManager:
volumes:
      - ./libs/flink-connector-kafka-1.17.2.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-connector-kafka-1.17.2.jar
      - ./libs/flink-shaded-guava-30.1.1-jre-16.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-shaded-guava-30.1.1-jre-16.0.jar
      - ./libs/kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar

I tested and i was able to create a table using Flink SQL
but even when i ran the query in Flink SQL it failed with the missing kafka lib error.
I was also able to connect to Kafka from Flink JobManager.
UPDATE:
I added the flink-sql-connector in docker-compose.yml file.
This is the classpath in the Flink JobManager now:
/opt/flink/lib/flink-cep-1.18.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-connector-files-1.18.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-csv-1.18.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-json-1.18.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-scala_2.12-1.18.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-table-planner-loader-1.18.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-table-runtime-1.18.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-dist-1.18.1.jar

When i run the container with the PyFlink client, there is no submitted job to the cluster, and nothing is running.
When i am opening a bash shell in the JobManager and run Flink SQL, i am able to create the table, and run
SELECT * FROM kafka_test_logs

which seems to be submitting the job to the JobManager but i don't think it is actually consuming any data.
When i ran
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --describe --group flink_group

I got message:
Error: Consumer group 'flink_group' does not exist.

Which i think means that Flink did not actually read any messages from the topic.
The stdout in the Flink UI tab of the JobManager is empty.
There is a running job which is collect.
In the logs of the TaskManager there is:
2024-04-05 10:49:50,560 INFO  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer [] - [Consumer clientId=flink_group-0, groupId=flink_group] Assigned to partition(s): action-logs-0
2024-04-05 10:49:50,564 INFO  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState [] - [Consumer clientId=flink_group-0, groupId=flink_group] Seeking to earliest offset of partition action-logs-0
2024-04-05 10:49:50,777 INFO  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata [] - [Consumer clientId=flink_group-0, groupId=flink_group] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition action-logs-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to S-TibAYBSo2SWb5WWF1mvg
2024-04-05 10:49:50,778 INFO  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata [] - [Consumer clientId=flink_group-0, groupId=flink_group] Cluster ID: 0ogSJvvhQ2Oghei-w8JpHA
2024-04-05 10:49:50,787 INFO  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState [] - [Consumer clientId=flink_group-0, groupId=flink_group] Resetting offset for partition action-logs-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}.
2024-04-05 10:58:51,071 INFO  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [] - [Consumer clientId=flink_group-0, groupId=flink_group] Node -1 disconnected.

The logs in the Flink JobManager include logs like:
2024-04-05 10:49:50,330 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: kafka_action_logs[1] -> Sink: Collect table sink (1/1) (713f3f67350c629be110f6ffdae3c6c2_cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0_0) switched from INITIALIZING to RUNNING.
2024-04-05 10:49:50,331 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinator [] - Source Source: kafka_action_logs[1] registering reader for parallel task 0 (#0) @ 192.168.32.8
2024-04-05 10:49:50,346 INFO  org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator [] - Discovered new partitions: [action-logs-0]
2024-04-05 10:49:50,350 INFO  org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator [] - Assigning splits to readers {0=[[Partition: action-logs-0, StartingOffset: -2, StoppingOffset: -9223372036854775808]]}
2024-04-05 10:49:50,376 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectSinkOperatorCoordinator [] - Sink connection established
2024-04-05 10:54:50,340 INFO  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [] - [AdminClient clientId=flink_group-enumerator-admin-client] Node -1 disconnected.

Why would the job get submitted from the Flink SQL console but not the actual Flink client container?
Also, how can i print out the results, i.e. count of messages, to check that Flink can actually consume messages from the Kafka topic?
Could it be that the JAR file of the Flink SQL connector is not compatible with the Flink docker image i am using?

The connectors (including the Flink Kafka one) aren't bundled with Flink. If you want to use them, you'll need to add them yourself to your Docker image. Given that you try to run a SQL statement, you'll need to add the flink-sql-kafka connector, and that also must be a compatible version with your Flink version. The SQL variant shades all the necessary dependency in, so you don't need add things like Kafka Client JARs yourself. That's important, since the connector is compatible with specific Kafka CLients JARs.
So bottomline, you'll need to include something in your Dockerfile like
RUN wget -P /opt/flink/lib https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-sql-connector-kafka/3.1.0-1.18/flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar


Thanks @Martijn Visser. I added the JAR as suggested and updated the initial description.

Is there a way to find which connector version is compatible with Kafka and Flink?
I am using Flink: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12 and Kafka: bitnami/kafka:latest
I am still getting error:
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factory for identifier 'kafka' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory' in the classpath.
In /opt/flink/lib, for both TaskManager and JobManager there is:
flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar
